# SLAAC won't disable on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ipv6

I cannot properly disable SLAAC on my Ubuntu 17.10 as there are always 2 dynamic addresses present.

NetworkManager is not installed at all. `/etc/network/interfaces` only has loopback configured.

[image: Screenshot with configurations]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add

```
accept-ra: no
```

to your `netplan` config for the desired interface. According to the manpage of `netplan`

```
man netplan
```

this option prevents the kernel from configuring IPv6 by itself on basis of the Router Advertisment sent to your server.